# Is there any intermediate fields between these two fields？

Tags: abstract-algebra, complex-numbers, extension-field, transcendental-numbers

Is there any intermediate fields between the algebraic closure of the rational field and the complex field？
Can I get such a field by adding a transcendental number and then taking the algebraic closure over the complex field？
If so，how can I prove it？

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: what is the cardinality of the algebraic closure of the rationals? And therefore, what is the cardinality of an extension of this field by a sinlge transcendental element? And the cardinality of the algebraic closure of the new obtained field?

On the other hand, what is the cardiniality of the complex numbers?

Comment: I don’t get your point.

Comment: If the resulting field extension was the complex numbers, they would be countable right? So he can get such an intermediate field using this procedure

Comment: Yes, but the questioner was asking about whether there is *any* intermediate fields between the algebraic coluse of $ℚ$ and $ℂ$ and whether one can obtain such fields by taking the algebraic closure after adjoining a transcendental element to $ℚ$. So for some of these fields, it’s impossible, but for others …?

Comment: Yes, and I tried to justify that there must be many such intermediate fields. The algebraic closure of $\mathbb{Q}$ is countable, and so is the result of further adjoining a transcendental element over $\mathbb{Q}$. This field is not the algebraic closure of $\mathbb{Q}$ because it has a transcendent element but it is also not the complex number because it is countable. Right?

Comment: I get it now, yes. I misunderstood what you were hinting at.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, of course there are such fields.

Let $L = \overline ℚ ⊆ ℂ$ be the algebraic closure of $ℚ$ within $ℂ$. Then $L$ is algebraically closed and algebraic over $ℚ$. For any transcendental number $α ∈ ℂ$, the algebraic closure $L_α = \overline ℚ(α) ⊆ ℂ$ within $ℂ$ of $ℚ(α)$ is an algebraically closed field with $ℚ ⊆ L_α$. So $L ⊆ L_α$. Since $α$ is transcendental $α \notin L$, so the inclusion is strict.

You can do this construction with every subset $A ⊆ ℂ$ instead of just some $α ∈ ℂ$. Whenever $A$ contains transcendental elements, you end up with a proper field extension $L_A$ of $L = \overline ℚ$. In fact, you can get *every* algebraically closed intermediate extension $E / L$ this way, because you may take $A = E$, so $L_E = E$. However, there might be extensions $E / L$ that are not algebraically closed …

However, you can’t get all intermediate extensions by only doing this with single elements $α$ (or even finite or countable sets $A ⊆ ℂ$), as pointed out / hinted at by Pedro.

An alternative way to see that $L_α ≠ ℂ$ is to consider algebraically independent elements. Say, if $α, β ∈ ℂ$ are algebraically independent over $ℚ$, then $β \notin L_α$.

Comment: It seems clear to me (also by the title of the question) that what the OP wants to know is whether there are PROPER intermediate fields or not. This is not fully answered by you (you need to use the hint I give in my answer, which is I think the only not completely obvious part). Moreover, you gave the exact same argument that I just gave you in the comments of my answer. I am sorry but I don't think your attitude was completely fair. This is why I downvoted your answer. Sorry if your attitude was fair and you already had this argument in mind before I said it in the comments.

Comment: @Pedro Yes, I get that. I did not repeat your argument because you already wrote it up. Instead, I referred to it.

Comment: But either way if you didn't get the point of my answer, you did not have in mind a justification of this extension not being the whole of $\mathbb{C}$, right?

Comment: @Pedro I did. I also think you misinterpret what downvotes are for.

Comment: You need to justify why the algebraic closure of $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$ is not $\mathbb{C}$. This algebraic closure is by definition algebraically closed, just as $\mathbb{C}$, so cardinality is really something you need in your argument. And you don't mention this. Hence, you are not answering the question. Hence the downvote (even disregarding all the other details).

Comment: @Pedro Okay, I don’t care to give the argument because you already did. I don’t see a point in repeating your argument. I referred to your answer. Instead, I discussed which fields you can get this way.

Comment: @Pedro However, I wrote up an alternative argument.

Comment: I think you didn't, you only reformulated the problem: how do you know that two algebraically independent elements exist over $\mathbb{Q}$? Maybe there is actually an argument to show this without using cardinality, but in any case you didn't give it. Anyway, this is not such an important discussion and MSE is already suggesting to use the chat, so I will let it be here. No hard feelings I hope! Regards,

Comment: @Pedro For example by [Lindemann–Weierstraß](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_independence#Lindemann–Weierstrass_theorem).